# String buzzing even after straightening neck from shop

Tags: guitar, maintenance

I had my guitar's neck straightened from a shop, the action now is very comfortable as compared to before but I'm still getting buzzing before the 12th frets on all strings but its too much in the G string. Should I take it back to the shop or can it be easily fixed at home? I have fender MZ5 Mexican strat. Also should my guitars neck be completely straight? The guy at the shop told me its fine but I read some articles that it should be a little concave forward.

Comment: Another service for you to consider -- whether on your own, or via the shop -- is to level your frets. This is an essential step to minimizing the action height. Level frets plus a slightly concave relief will yield the best action. Then it is a matter of cutting the nut and setting the bridge (saddle) heights to personal taste. Finally, adjust the intonation again and you should be ready to go.

Comment: I've had similar trouble, and it turned out that the real issue was that my frets were worn down.  I ended up getting a re-fret job and problem solved.  I'm not saying this is your issue, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straightening a guitar's neck is easy to do at home - if you know what you're doing. You took it to a shop, because you felt they knew the job better. Take it back, explain the problem. It may be they've adjusted it too far, it may be the guitar won't take all the adjustment, it may be it just needs the action tweaking.Whichever, the job's been paid for and it's not a good 'un. If you can be there while it's being worked on, do that. At least you'll have some idea as to how the mechanics works for another time. Necks are rarely dead straight, there's usually a bit of relief - the strings need a bit of space in which to vibrate. Sounds like there's not quite enough on your guitar.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'll just strictly tell them not not keep it so straight.

Comment: There's always a trade-off between the straightness of the neck and the action that results from it. String tension is another factor, and if they get changed, it may precipitate sorting out the intonation. Pandora's box comes to mind !

Comment: Yeah I took it back to the shop and he gave the neck a little relief and now all the buzzing is gone. Maybe for the next time I can do it myself.